# Dates in UIDatepicker not displaying properly

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults, uidatepicker

I have UIDatepicker .I have few queries to ask

1.)When i tap on UIButton the dates in datepicker gets retuns to minimum value since i have given maximum and minimum value . In doing that function the date in datepicker appears to be in non highlighted manner ![enter image description here. The link mentioned below shows how the date appears in datepicker

http://postimg.org/image/7mlxiq6sz/

-

```
(IBAction)notificationButtonChanged:(UIButton *)control
{

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if (control.tag == 1)
    {
        self.selectedButton = control.tag;

        NSDate *date1  = [defaults objectForKey:@"morningTimeKey"];
        if(!date1) date1 = [NSDate date];

        components = [gregorian components: NSUIntegerMax fromDate:date1];

        [components setHour:12];;
        [components setMinute:00];

        NSDate *startDate = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];

        [components setHour:14];
        [components setMinute:00];

        NSDate *endDate = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];

        [userTimePicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeTime];

        [userTimePicker setMinimumDate:startDate];
        [userTimePicker setMaximumDate:endDate];

        [userTimePicker setDate:date1 animated:YES];

        [userTimePicker reloadInputViews];
    }

}
```

Comment: Please tell me one thing how you are assigning NSDate to NSString by using this NSDate *date1  = [defaults objectForKey:@"morningTimeKey"]; Also  plaese NSLog your morning key before assigning it's value to NSDate

Comment: your link is also not responding you can post your image here

Comment: @AshutoshMishra...i am using @'morningTimeKey" to store the value in NSUserDefaults ... the link is working ..open in new tab

Comment: I am just just saying when you are assigning @"morningTimeKey" to date please just log it to see it is correct or not

Comment: @RaviTrivedi .. i am assigning time in timePicker only ...the problem is it appearing in less highlighted manner that is if startTime is 12 .."12" comes in less bold color ..idk why ..it should come in normal bold color

Comment: where is your `gregorian` object defined ?